# chrome.runtime.setUninstallUrl doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, uninstallation

I'm trying to make my chrome extension visit an URL when it is uninstalled. Apparently [`chrome.runtime.setUninstallUrl`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL) is the best (and only?) option, but it doesn't seem to work for me. It's not firing at all.

This is the code I use:

```
chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL('www.google.com');
```

It's located in the extension's background JavaScript file together with a couple of other event listeners. I tried loading my unpacked extension into Chrome and then removing it, but the uninstall URL does not budge.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

The feature landed in Chrome 41, so the answer is mostly obsolete - it should work now.

---

The documentation displays a warning:

> **Dev** channel only.

This means that this API function is still considered experimental and not enabled in Stable/Beta builds of Chrome.

Here's the [corresponding issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84556) in the Chrome bug tracker. Seems like this feature should hit stable soon (ready since July) but got a bit lost on its way. Consider starring the issue to raise its priority.

---

Until it is fixed, it won't work in normal Chrome versions. You should have seen an error that the function is undefined if you looked in the background console, by the way.

You can already safely include it in your code conditionally, so it will work on builds where it's enabled:

```
if(chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL) {
  chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL('http://example.com/');
} else {
  // Not yet enabled
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I now tried it on a dev build and it indeed works there, but not on stable. Guess I'll have to wait, because it seems this is the only way to achieve what I want.

Comment: This finally made it into the stable channel since Chrome 41 https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-setUninstallURL

Comment: @JosephPortelli Feel free to write an answer about it and ask OP to move the accepted mark.

Answer (score 5):

The URL must have an http: or https: scheme.

Comment: Correct observation, wouldn't work as given in the example (`"www.google.com"`).