# Chrome setUninstallURL is not capturing all uninstall events

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We currently have the listener for setUninstallURL and we capture the event / pageview;

However, this number does NOT match the Chrome Webstore "Uninstalls" of our chrome web extension.

I have emailed CWS support a few times, but cant find an answer.

Are there uninstalls recorded by CWS that aren't triggering this event?
Which other listeners / events should we add to ensure we capture all Uninstalls?

Comment: Many users simply close the tab that pops up on uninstall due to the automatic reflex of closing ad pop-under tabs so the request won't reach your server. P.S. I've seen this question asked before, try searching.

Comment: are you certain your url is always up?

Comment: You may want to check this related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752114/chrome-runtime-setuninstallurl-doesnt-seem-to-be-working) which mentioned about a [fixed issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84556) logged in Chrome bug tracker and see if it will help. I know it's an old post, hope it helps.

Comment: @wOxxOm searching for the setUninstallURL and chrome yeilds a handful of results, do you have something else you've seen. Sometimes peoples brains work better than others for trivia. But good point on autoclose reflex.

Comment: @Teyam yes, and we log it so fast that theres no human way a mouseclick can beat a few MS delay. 

3-6 servers, 99.9999% uptime; logging as needed.